# The server tag is not well formed.asp.net LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

Linkbutton giving this error.Few days before it was working fine suddenly it is giving error

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="College Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSelectCollege" OnClientClick="MyLstCollege('<%#Eval("Name")%>');
return false;" ForeColor="Black" runat="server" TabIndex="-1">
<a style="cursor:pointer"><%#Eval("Name")%></a>
</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: i am trying to select value on linkbutton

Comment: Thank you Nag taking interest in my question i solved the problem myself

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-arrange the single and double quotes in `OnClientClick`

*Change*

```
OnClientClick="MyLstCollege('<%#Eval("Name")%>');return false;"
```

*To*

```
OnClientClick='<%# MyLstCollege(Eval("Name") %>); return false;'
```

Comment: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line

Comment: Check my updated answer, there was a typo extra semi colon at the end which I removed.

Comment: solved the problem  replaced linkbutton with this :                <a style="text-decoration: none; color: Black; cursor: pointer;" title="Select" onclick="MyLstStatus('<%#Eval("Name")%>')"
                                    tabindex="-1">
                                    <%#Eval("Name")%></a>

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem replaced linkbutton with this

```
<a style="text-decoration: none; color: Black; cursor: pointer;" title="Select"   onclick="MyLstStatus('<%#Eval("Name")%>')" tabindex="-1"> <%#Eval("Name")%></a>
```